# Angular: Import different scripts depending on the environment

Tags: javascript, angular, environment-variables

I am developing a web application in Angular (version 2+). This application must work in two environments: **test** and **production**.
I need to use an external script. When imported this way, everything works:

**File angular.json**:

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/my_folder/dev/my_script.js"
           ]
```

In `my_folder` are the **dev** and **prod** folders. The application works perfectly in the Development environment, but I have no idea how to do a "dynamic variation" of this path with the path `"src/assets/my_folder/prod/my_script.js"` when the application is actually deployed in the production environment.

Is there some sort of "best practice" in Angular for doing this thing?

Comment: Look into [configuring app environments](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments).

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 2):

You can use `angular.json` to configure various environment

```
"configurations": {
    "dev": {
      "scripts": [
          "src/assets/my_folder/dev/my_script.js"
      ]   
    },
    "prod": {
      "scripts": [
          "src/assets/my_folder/prod/my_script.js"
      ]  
    }
}
```

[Alternate build configurations](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-configs)